# How can I install a WinPE image to internal HDD

Tags: hard-drive, winpe

I have an ISO image of "Bob.Omb's modified Win10PEx64 v3.8" which I wish to install to a machine's internal hdd. How can I achieve this?

(The point of this exercise is that I want to build a custom PE image to be a lightweight arcade cabinet OS, which will be placed on the machine's internal storage. I'm using Bob.Omb's custom PE image to experiment.)

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

- Follow [Microsoft's instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-install-on-a-hard-drive--flat-boot-or-non-ram) for installing WinPE on HDD> using the *CopyPE*, *DiskPart*, *DISM* and BCDboot, which are on the [Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit (Windows ADK)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/get-started/adk-install#winADK).
- Using [Rufus](https://web.sas.upenn.edu/jasonrw/tag/rufus/).

Comment: I tried Rufus originally but it would not display any drive which was not a USB drive. So I guess I'll go with option A. Thanks.

Comment: I had hoped perhaps someone had developed a 3rd party tool to streamline the process a bit but I guess not :/

Comment: Are you able to explain the following part of the MS instructions regarding BCD? 
"BCDboot P:\Windows /s P: /f ALL"
They say what to do, but don't explain why. So I'm not able to properly customise the string for my paths and receive error: Failure when attempting to copy boot files

Comment: See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcdboot-command-line-options-techref-di which fully explains BCDboot and its command line options (*/s, /f and ALL*) used here.